# Magento Bulk Product Import + Modules Nightmare

Tags: magento

1. Have 5,000 products in CSV file
2. File has been re-saved as UT8 file in google documents and exported to CSV from excel
3. File loads perfectly with all fields in demo of magento store manager (except we dont want to buy it:)
4. When trying to upload in regular Magento..keep getting error messages on column duplicates....yes we have hundreds of duplicates as the titles of products in fields correspond with different sizes, etc...no way around it
5. Any solutions around this or any open source software similar to store manager that can do the trick.  Ready to give up and go to paid solution such as Big Commerce
6. Also, Uploaded a bunch of free modules/keys...of open source bulk import products from magentocommerce  but I cant find them anywhere in the main admin panel to use...there is no menu item for them anywhere??

Answer (score 1):

Bit hard to answer without seeing your csv, however the only duplicate values that Magento should care about is the SKU, so make sure these are unique.

Is your csv file formatted correctly? ie; correct headers? Did you create the csv from an export of Magento data?

Magento will also complain about any extended ascii characters in your data, such as MS Word apostrophes, quotes, elipses, etc. so make sure you replace these with ascii variants

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate products can be caused when SKU from the file you import  do not match to the SKU in your store.
If the SKU not defined or path is not valid there should be wrong characters in the import file. So check your title and all fields which contain text.